# Firestore Arrays vs. Object with Indexes

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I am designing my Firestore schema and am a bit confused as to the best way to structure it.

I have Users, Products and ShoppingLists.

Should my Shopping lists which are separate documents have UUID fields or an array field of UUIDs for the Users that have access to that shopping list?

Same with Products.

Is one better or worse for querying?

Answer (score 0):

Best to not use arrays at this time and just use a map of UUIDs set to true or such